# Ignore data race report by thread sanatizer

Tags: c++, multithreading, clang, thread-safety

How can I tell Clangs thread sanatizer to ignore a detected data race?

My program has a data race that I am not bothered about and don't want to "fix". I have a debug UI that observers a dynamic system. The system is constantly changing and the UI reads values of the system from another thread. This obviously has a data race, but as far as I understand the data within the system should not be affected by reads from another thread, and I don't mind if sometimes the debug UI displays garbage values. Also making the system use synchronization would incur unnecessary overhead in runtime and development time.

Am I correct in thinking that this is not an issue and is there a way to tell thread sanatizer to ignore the data race?

I guess standard C++ makes little or no guaratees in this case but I specifically would like to know about the behaviour on x86 architecture.

Here is an example for the sake of demonstration:

```cpp
double sharedValue = 0.0;

void logicThread() {
    while (true) {
        sharedValue += 0.333;
    }
}

void uiTread() {
    while (window.open()) {
        window.display(sharedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need synchronisation, just atomicity. Is it too much to change it to `std::atomic<double> sharedValue = 0.0;` and `sharedValue = sharedValue + 0.333;` ?

Comment: You don't just have to worry about values being updated at inconvenient times and printing garbage, you also have to worry about the optimizer. Since `sharedValue` never changes in `uiTread`'s while loop, the compiler is well with its rights to optimize `window.display(sharedValue);` into something like `window.display(some_constant_value);`. Proper synchronization will solve this problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, I figured that shortly after posting the question. I think in my program the reads are sufficiently insulated and I don't use LTO so that _should_ not be an issue but your point is true nonetheless.

Comment: @Artyer It would be kind of a substantial change. The shared value is actually an array of values and pointers to elements of that array are used all over the place, changing them all would be very time consuming. And I am somewhat concerned about performance since atomics prohibit many optimizations but I haven't benchmarked of course.

Comment: One option: Don't let the background tasks do much work directly on `sharedValue`. Instead have them operate on something more local and at reasonable intervals pay the cost, which may turn out to be negligible, of updating a `std::atomic` `sharedValue`. If you can afford to show the occasional junk value, you can probably afford for it to not be real-time.